# How to get the memory usage in XPages SSJS

Tags: xpages-ssjs

Here's the scenario:
The user fills up a form and clicks "Create PDF" button.
Then a pdf is generated based on the filled up user form.

This is implemented in Domino Designer on Domino Server using a XPage, a Custom Controls and a Script Libraries (SSJS).

I want to monitor the MEMORY USAGE each time the PDF is generated for optimization purposes.
I understand I need to add a line of code to the start and the end of
of my code (where pdf is generated).

Is there a method to get the Memory Usage in SSJS?

I'm an intern (developer) and have a lot to learn.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other methods but if you use the debug Toolbar by  Mark Leusink, one of the many useful features (in the Environment & Java tab) is memory usage.  It is a good way of troubleshooting as well.

http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPage+Debug+Toolbar